# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: always called

Tags: ios, push-notification

I've seen a lot of questions on here about this method *never* being called, but I'm seeing the opposite behavior.

When I first install an test app with no other code other than the call to register for push notifications, I receive the pop up on my device to accept or decline. Before I choose either, the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method is being called. Additionally, even if I then choose not to receive notifications, the didRegister method is called each time the application is launched.

The token is a valid one, though when I try to send notifications to that device, I don't receive the notifications, which makes sense. If I flip the setting in the Settings app, the token does become valid, though. I'm guessing (I can't do much else at this point) that you receive a token regardless of the user's preference, so that in the scenario that they do change it in the Settings app, you're able to use it immediately. I feel like this wasn't the way it used to work, but maybe I'm just imagining it.

Additionally, and as a side note, even after I uninstall and reinstall, I'm not being re-prompted to accept or decline notifications. Is there a way to clear this?

Answer (score 0):

that's how it *should* be. The documentation explicitely states that you must not save the token to some persistent storage. instead, you should keep it in RAM and retrieve it each time the app launches.

2.) no, the only way to clear it is to reset the device.

Comment: Are you saying it should be called every time, even if they decline? That's what I wasn't sure about, and couldn't find any documentation around. I'm not saving it for actual use, I just started holding onto it when I realized it was getting called every time to figure out if it was a valid token. Just for the sake of testing out this issue.

Comment: if they decline, you don't get a token. instead, you will receive an error

Comment: if the user deactivates push notifications after having accepted it, you keep the push token, but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: i know it's a bit crappy this way ;) i think there is some way to check which types of push notifications are enabled (e.g. sound, badges, etc.) and if nothing is enabled you know that the user has disabled it in the settings. the device token becomes invalid when you uninstall the app. the next time you try to send with this token, an error is generated and appended to some list. to fetch this list you need to fetch the apns feedback url to get a list of device tokens corresponding to uninstalled apps.

Comment: To your first comment, that's not what I'm seeing -- that's what my question is about. I declined, but still received the didRegister event.

Comment: did you decline in your app? or did you go to the systemwide settings app and decline there?

Comment: because if you decline in the systemwide settings app, you will keep the device token...

Comment: I declined from my app, when the popup showed on first launch. That's the part that confused me -- from past experience, I was under the impression that would cause the error method to be called, but that's not what I saw. Maybe I'll make another one off application to test that out quick.

Comment: that's strange. i would put a breakpoint in the method when this happens, and see what's going on. is it really called by the system? or is some other method of yours calling this method? does the token seem valid? or is it nil?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51980/discussion-between-shortstuffsushi-and-michael)